# How to merge neighbouring patches with same value to reduce processing time?

Tags: merge, netlogo

since my model becomes huge (around 17.500 patches and 2.000 turtles that have to compare each others opinions about every patch with all other turtles) I was wondering if there is a smart solution to merge patches in order to reduce the number of patch IDs.  The number of turtles has already been reduced by making groups of 10. However, processing will probably still take for ages....

For all patches I created an dictionary that stores an ID as key and an value for opinion based on landuse and distance. I have four different landuse classes with value 1-4. What I thought about was about asking the the neighbours if they have the same landuse value. If this is true all patches should get the same ID and the same opinion in the dictionary as the patch in the middle. This is something I tried out, but it did not work. Besides, I think I also need to handle the pitfall that patches that have already been merged are calculated over and over again....

```
 let dummy one-of patches
 ask dummy with [value = 1] [
 set value myself
 ask neighbors4 [
   if value = 1
   [set id [id] of dummy]]]
```

If you have any suggestion, how I might approach in a decent way, please let me know.

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: Are you also trying to merge larger groups of similar neighbours, or only the specific case of a '+' shaped group of 5? I can't draft code without being clear on the rules, but I think you probably want to use the `patch-set` primitive to create your groups and assign all members the same value. You can avoid the already merged problem by excluding those already with an assigned value from the checking if it should be merged part.

Comment: Have you looked at Patch Clusters Example, in the Code Examples section of the Models Library?